# How to implement timer in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement a timer in asp.net web in which, after a time period, the text of a button is changed. I created the button dynamically in gridview and tried this code:

```
protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " +
    DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    for(int i = 0; i< rowcount; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        if (button.Text == "requested")
        {
            button.Text = "available";
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: To change the text of the button you created in the GridView, you need a reference to that Button object, Button button = new Button() simply creates a new Button object which has no relation to the previously created Button in the GridView..

Answer (score 2):

This requires client code (JavaScript) that executes on the browser after the page is loaded. ASP.NET generates the page, sends it to the browser, and then the server is done with it until it gets another request. Even if you create a timer in your code-behind, that code-behind is a class that goes out of scope and disappears once the server is done processing the request.

In its simplest form, it would look something like this:

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        //do something
    }, 10000); //interval in milliseconds - this is 10 seconds.
<script>
```

In order to be able to change text, you'll need to make sure that your control has an ID that you can find using JavaScript. Usually whatever ID you use for a server control, ASP.NET is going to modify it somewhat. I'm oversimplifying this, but generally you can do this:

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabelId" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="The label text"></asp:Label>
```

or

```
<div runat="Server" ID="MyLabelId" ClientIDMode="Static">The label text</div>
```

`ClientIdMode="Static"` means that when the control is rendered to the page it won't modify the ID.

Then your script might look like this:

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        var label = document.getElementById("MyLabelId");
        label.textContent = "The new value";
    }, 10000); 
<script>
```

Or instead of using `ClientIDMode="Static"` you could try this in your script:

```
var label = document.getElementById("<%= MyLabelId.ClientID %>");
```

`.ClientID` is whatever ID the page assigns to the control. This tells it that whatever ID it assigns to that control, to write it directly into your script.